# Unexpected React error when passing state down

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Right now, I have this code (showing generic):

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const parentComponent = () => {

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

return 
(<>
<childComponent setShowDependent={() => setShow(true)} />
{ show && <dependentComponent /> }
</>);

}

const childComponent = ({setShowDependent}) => {
 return <Button onClick={setShowDependent} />;
}
```

and I am getting the warning in react dev tools:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`parentComponent`) while rendering a different component (`childComponent`).
```

and it is not working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that in the code that u posted here, u deleted the part that was wrong BTW please put ur code on codesandbox (codesandbox.io) and come back here (:

Answer (score 0):

React component name must start with an uppercase letter

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const ParentComponent = () => {

const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

return (<>
<ChildComponent setShowDependent={() => setShow(true)} />
{ show && <DependentComponent /> }
</>);

}

const ChildComponent = ({setShowDependent}) => {
 return <Button onClick={setShowDependent} />;
}
```

Comment: I think this is an example and that's why he used a simple example.
and also I guess there is not relation between main problem and what u said.

Comment: I run your example and work without any problem in my local. I think you must add more detail to your question.

Comment: This is not my question. It is better to mention the author of the question

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry 